# Cómo saber si es la última iteración de un foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Tengo una función que concatena un query a partir de variables POST, esto lo hago con un foreach:

```
$id = $_POST['empId'];
$query = "UPDATE userInfo SET ";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $query .= "$key = '$value', ";
}
$query .= " WHERE id = '$id'";
```

¿Cómo puedo saber cuando es la ultima iteración, para poder quitarle la coma final y así poder construir el query de forma correcta??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función de array de php [end()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.end.php). La función, como puedes leer en el enlace, establece el puntero en el último elemento del array. Si lo evaluas con un condicional puede conseguir lo que propones de una manera bastante limpia y eficaz;

```
$id = $_POST['empId'];
$query = "UPDATE userInfo SET ";
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === end($keys)) {
        $query .= "$key = '$value'";
    } else {
        $query .= "$key = '$value', ";
    }
}
$query .= " WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Esto realmente no es recomendable, si hay por ejemplo un Array como este `array('pie', 'bici', 'coche', 'pie')` en el que el último elemento coincide en valor con otro obtendremos un resultado no deseado.

Comment: Tienes razón, he cambiado el código de manera que no cometa ese error. Gracias por el aviso

Comment: Excelente me funciono! (Y)

Answer (score 6):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con la función [`implode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php), en lugar de concatenar al string agrega elementos a un arreglo y por último haces un `implode`

```
$id = $_POST['empId'];
$query = "UPDATE userInfo SET ";
$queryParams = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $queryParams[] = "$key = '$value'";
}
$params = implode(', ', $queryParams);
$query = $query . $params . " WHERE id = '$id'";
```

---

Como nota aparte parece que estás expuesto a un ataque de [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), en este post se habla de manera extendida sobre como evitarla: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo, solo debes consultar las keys del arreglo y luego comprobar si efectivamente estas en la ultima

```
<?php

//Leo cuantos elementos hay en el array
$cont = count($_POST);
//Consulto las keys del array
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
//Busco la ultima
$ultima_key = $keys[$cont-1];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $ultima_key){
        echo "Esta es la ultima iteracion\n";
    }else{
        echo "Esta no es la ultima iteracion\n";
    }    
}

?>
```

Comment: Para obtener la última key seria más fácil hacer `end($array);
$last_key = key($array);` es decir avanzar el puntero interno a la última posición y obtener la clave.

Comment: Desconozco en profundidad la funcion end ¿No modifica el puntero interno del array?

Comment: Si `end(): Establece el puntero interno de un array a su último elemento`, no entiendo cual es el problema. No afecta en absoluto al foreach ya que reinicia el puntero o itera sobre una copia según la version de php.

Comment: No sabia eso, gracias por aclararlo

Answer (score 0):

Actualización 2020. **PHP 7.3** o superior introduce las funciones

[array_key_first()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-first.php)
Obtiene la primera clave del array dado sin afectar el puntero de array interno.

[array_key_last()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-last.php)
Obtiene la última clave del array dado sin afectar el puntero de array interno.

Ejemplo obteniendo la última iteración, dado un arreglo llamado `$array`:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    // ... 
    if ($key === array_key_last($array)) {
        echo 'Esta es la última iteracion';
    }
    // ... 
}
```